# how to manage the textview and textview text?

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that i use the textviews.IN that textviews there is a some gap between textview starting point and text.So please tell me how to decrease that gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setContentInset message on the UITextView object and play around with the value passed to setContentInset as parameter. An example:

```
[yourTextView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8,-8,0,0)];
```

Where yourTextView is your UITextView object.